# connecting ceiling light to existing, what to do with the only existing red

Tags: electrical, lighting

My kitchen light works on a dimmer switch. In my original setup the light (from 2002) had some sort of transformer box inside the top with two red wires on one end, one black and one white on the other end, these connected the transformer to the the black and white leads from the light itself (black-black) and (white-white) and the two reds connected to a single red wire in the ceiling box. The ceiling box itself has 3 black together, 3 white together and the single red, I guess it's two incoming 14-2 wires with a single incoming 14-3 wire. The dimmer only operates the kitchen light though, and it's the only switch in the house that does this. My new light has no red, only a black and white with a ground, apparently it's a dimmable light, but there's no transformer like my old light. If I connect the red to the three blacks that are together in the box, then add in the black from the new light fixture, that's a lot of wires in a single marret. Right now I have a temporary construction pony-tail light (black and white only) and it doesn't work with the switch, I have to unscrew it to turn it off. I have the black with the other 3 blacks, and the white with the other 3 whites. Any advice would be very much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Can you please post photos of the labeling on the transformer?

Comment: Clear, focused pics of the wiring behind the switch, the wiring in the box, and the wiring diagram of the new light. Without them, your wall-o-text is very hard to decipher. Also, do _NOT_ disconnect any of the wiring, just pull the devices from the wall so we can see how the wires are attached to the devices and to the cables coming into the boxes.